# Woocommerce Pre Orders - Can i override templates?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to override the woocommerce pre-order plugin templates.

I tried the same method that woocommerce uses to override plugins

(copied the templates folder into my theme folder) but nothing happens.

I tried with simple echo "hello world" on the page, but nothing. Is there a way to override these templates?

The plugin structure is the following:

```
woocommerce-pre-orders
 |_ templates
  |_ email
  |_ myaccount
```

and i tried to override them like this in my theme (removing the template folder like woocommerce requires):

```
my-theme
 |woocommerce-pre-orders
  |_ email
  |_ myaccount
```

and i also tried like this:

```
my-theme
 |woocommerce-pre-orders
  |_ templates
   |_ email
   |_ myaccount
```

None of the above worked.

Any help?

thanks a log

Comment: Hi. WooCommerce questions are off-topic here by their own. However you can discuss your problem in [WooCommerce](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61002/woocommerce) chat room.

Comment: oh ok, sorry i didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know